# Different ways to destructing unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I analyze a class with unique_ptr member. That member may be used from  different threads. There is also a method which destroys that member:

```
void uninitialize()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Worker> worker;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx_);
        worker = std::move(worker_);
    }
}
```

I wonder what is purpose of that impl. Is there any difference between the above and the following implementation? :

```
void uninitialize()
{ 
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx_);
    worker_.reset();
}
```

Worker doesn't define move constructor.

Comment: Assuming `worker_` doesn't have something that runs on another thread, the practical difference is time spend in the mutex, basically if `~Worker()` takes a long time and another thread try to access `worker_`, then you would prefer the first version.

Answer (score 9):

The difference is that in the first snippet, the mutex will only be held for long enough for `worker` to take ownership of the object that `worker_` owns; the destruction of that object will be unguarded. In the second snippet, the mutex will not be released until `.reset()` completes, which means it is held while the object is being destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `worker` ends up owning the `unique_ptr` (until it goes out of scope, without the lock held) In the second it is just destroyed (while the lock is held).